# Displaying Comment Count in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, crud

Within a simple CRUD rails app i'm working on, i'm using a comments gem called [Opinio](https://github.com/Draiken/opinio)

The model that is commentable is called posts. Within my view I am trying to output the comments count per post:

```
 <%= post.comments.size %>
```

This is only yielding the number of parent comments. It is not including the replies. How do I get the total number of comments per post, including the replies? Where is this gem storing the comment replies?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've browsed around the source code and [apparently](https://github.com/Draiken/opinio/blob/master/lib/opinio/shared_examples.rb) comments may be children of other comments but only up to one level: e.g. *comment1* belongs to *post1* and *comment2* belongs to *comment1* but *comment3* **can not** belong to *comment2* (because the parent of *comment2* is already another *Comment*).

So the query you need to make sounds like this: fetch all **parent comments** of *post1*, then fetch all **child comments** of the previous parent comments, then merge results. Something like:

```
class Post

  # This returns an Array of Comment objects. If you intend to use 
  # more than the #count method on the result, you should consider 
  # adding some sort of ordering on the two queries.
  def all_comments
    parent_comments = Comment.where(:commentable_id => id)
    child_comments = Comment.where(:commentable_id => parent_comments.map(&:id))
    parent_comments + child_comments
  end

end

post = Post.find(1)
post.all_comments.count # The number of all (parent & child) comments of post
```

If your *comment* class name is not **Comment** feel free to change it to whatever (same for **Post**).

Comment: Thank you soooooo much, you're a freaking genius and just saved me a world of headache! :))

Comment: And if I have more than one child in comments?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to retrieve the total number of comments on an individual post by using:

`@post = Post.find(params[:id])`in the controller and

`<%= post.comments.count %>`in the view.

To get all comments posted you could try

`@posts = Post.all` in the controller and

`<%= @posts.commments.count %>` in the view.

The comment replies will be stored in the database. Check the \db\migrate\ folder in your app and you should see the comments migration. If you look in the \db\ folder you should notice a development.sqlite3 database. Opening this using a database viewer will allow you to see the stored data.

**Update 1**

After reading through the Github repo I spotted a couple of things. Firstly I assume you are using Rails 3? (otherwise the engine doesn't work)

To display comments for a specific item opinio provides a method:

`opinio_identifier do |params|
next Review.find(params[:review_id]) if params[:review_id]
next Product.find(params[:product_id]) if params[:product_id]
end`

On this method you receive the params variable and you tell the engine who owns the comments from that page. This allows you to use routes like:

/products/1/comments

/products/1/reviews/1/

Ttwo customizations are only made through the opinio initializer, and they are the accept_replies which defaults to true and strip_html_tags_on_save which also defaults to true. You should be able to find this in the commentable model.

Maybe you could try this:

`<%= Opinio.model_name.comments.count %>` would change to

`<%= Opinio.post.comments.count %>`

Comment: I have already done this, can you take a look at the gem source code, and the dummy within the gem. I have looked at my schema, I have no clue where the replies are being stored. I just cant seem so find a way to count the comments and replies.

Comment: I have updated my original answer. Let me know if this is of any help to you.

Comment: The answer above was what I was looking for, but thanks anyway!